# Using D3 to tick time formatted axis

Tags: d3.js

I've found a lot of good documentation and tried a lot of different formatting but can't seem to get the dates actually ticking.

I realize my example code is a bit complicated but it's doing everything I wanted it to do and I figured I could go back and do the ticking within in a week (I have a filter that changes it to 30 days and 3 months, and all the dates are displayed so I really need to figure out how to properly format the axis for ticks to function:

http://jsbin.com/xacugeko/1/

I tried tickformat but it would just break, I also tried to set the scale to time instead of ordinal but was having trouble getting that to work as well.

New to D3 any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?